# Sending Tree Structure in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tree

I'm using the Arboreal library to send a tree structure to the frontend. However, I'm running into the issue of `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON]`, which is to be expected with a tree structure.

I want to maintain the object as it is so I can reuse the library on the front end. Is there any way I can send the object without node trying to interpret it?

Per node, tree contains information like:

```
depth: 0,
parent: [circular],
data: node data,
id: id,
children: [child node]
```

Comment: This isn't expected from a tree structure, as a tree is acyclic. Do you have a cyclic graph ? Can you tell more about it ? What do you want to do with it ?

Comment: The circular reference occurs from the parent node reference.

Comment: Why don't you just clone the "tree" and remove the parent references ? It's easy to restore them later.

Comment: Ideally, would like to reuse library without having to manipulate the data. But from the searches I've conducted, this doesn't seem possible. Thought I'd just post a question to see if anyone has any ideas. I may just have to strip out the circular references...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would clone the tree (not really a tree, in fact) and remove the `parent` references :

```
function cloneWithoutParent(n){
  if (typeof n !== "object") return n;  
  var c = {};
  for (var k in n) {
     if (k!=="parent") c[k] = cloneWithoutParent(n[k]); 
  }
  return c;
}
```

After that you can stringify the tree. Of course you can do the opposite to restore the `parent` property when you need the original structure.

Comment: I'll mark this correct, but I would still be interested in hearing any other options if any exist. Unrelated, but coming from a Java background, developing with node has had its challenges and frustrations for me.